# In Oracle SQL, how to get the time for only this current week?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query , where I want to obtain some data for different time durations (this month, this week, etc).

For the "this week" column, I want it to get all the data from the most recent Monday until now. How would I do this?

I have the following SQL so far :

```
WHERE  prla.CREATION_DATE >= SYSDATE - ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trunc(sysdate, 'iw')` is what you're after. IW is the format mask used for Monday of the week the specified date is in (as Monday is the ISO standard for the start of the week). E.g.:

```
with dates as (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 10 + level dt
               from   dual
               connect by level <= 40)
select dt
from   dates
where  dt >= trunc(sysdate, 'iw')
and    dt <= sysdate; -- only needed if the dates in the column could be beyond now.
```

Comment: Guaranteed to be NLS independent -- nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that will do: But it is better to use `sysdate-8`. Because if the current day is same as your searching day, it will return the current date. For Eg.

```
select next_day(sysdate-7,'WED') from dual;

OUTPUT
19-AUG-15
```

Whereas the below one will give you the last week

```
select next_day(sysdate-8,'WED') from dual;

OUTPUT
12-AUG-15
```

Answer (score 0):

You should truncate the current date.

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DAY')
```

This should give you the first day of the week, which is Monday in lot of countries.

If it's giving you the previous Sunday instead you should do this.

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DAY')+1
```

Comment: You might well want to Trunc() it, but you certainly wouldn't want to To_Char() it.

Comment: And in addition to what @DavidAldridge said, if you truncate to a day, you're just going to truncate to midnight of the date in question - ie. you just get rid of the time elements. This is the default for trunc, so `trunc(sysdate)` is the same as `trunc(sysdate, 'dd')`.

Comment: I think that DAY, DY, and D are indeed to the starting day of the week as defined by NLS_TERRITORY -- DDD, DD and J are to the day. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions270.htm#i1002084

Comment: Huh, well, that's my new thing learnt for today. I guess I should have read the documenation for trunc/round a little more closely, eh?! *{;-). Thanks for correcting me, @DavidAldridge. 'DAY' is still nls dependent though, so I would still shy away from it.

Comment: I'm accruing the benefit of not actually having used Oracle for about five years now -- I have to check everything!

Answer (score -1):

I found out to do this now:

```
select  next_day (sysdate-7, 'MONDAY') Last_Monday from dual;
```

So in my case, we can remove the SYSDATE subtraction and  it is simply :

```
 prla.CREATION_DATE >= next_day (sysdate-7, 'MONDAY')
```

[source](https://community.oracle.com/thread/680375)